# breaking out to multiple loops

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa, avaudioplayer

in my project I have multiple recordings taken from the iPhones microphone which I loop with this code

```
-(IBAction)loop1{ 
NSError *error;
audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:temporaryRecFile error:&error];
    audioPlayer.numberOfLoops = 100; 

[audioPlayer play];

}
```

and stop with this code

```
-(IBAction)loopstop1{ 

audioPlayer.numberOfLoops = 0; 

[audioPlayer stop];

}
```

When more than one recording is looping however this stop method only stops the last recording that was set to loop, I'm wondering if there is anyway to break out of all audio loops, or break these specific loops, as I am only managing to stop the last recording I have looped.

thanks for any help or advice

Comment: Why are you only storing the reference to one of the players, instead of all? You'll have to call `stop` on all players, not just the last one.

Comment: In your code, each time you call loop, you are creating another object audioPlayer object. With ARC, the old object, if still playing, will persist until it has finished. You stop method does not address. Instead of orphaning your objects you need to keep track of them, ie: `[audioPlayers_ addObject:newPlayer];` and then stop them with something like, `[audioPlayers_ makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(stop:)]`. Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks! Didn't realise I had created more than one player.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**What I would do :**

1. Create an `NSMutableArray` to hold the `audioPlayer`s
2. Add your `AVAudioPlayer` objects to your array

   ```
   AVAudioPlayer* newLoop = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:temporaryRecFile 
                                                                   error:&error];
   newLoop.numberOfLoops = 100; 

   [loopsArray addObject:newLoop];
   ```
3. Pass an index to each of the start / stop functions, to know which `audioPlayer` to start/stop.

---

***Hint :** To stop all of them, just call the `stop` method on each of your loops store in the `loopsArray`*